# Incrementing the X path in Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Folks,

I am new to python selenium. I have to increment the tr[] value in the below xpath

```
print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]")
```

Assumptions:

```
1. for i in range(1,10):
   print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[i]/td[3]")

2.for i in range(1,10):
   print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[str(i)]/td[3]")
```

None of my assumptions are working.Please share your suggestion with clear logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *string formatting* to get your Python variable into the XPath expression string:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[3]" % i)
```

Or, approach it a bit differently, find all `tr`s, slice and loop through them:

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr")[1:10]
for row in rows:
    print(row.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")[2].text)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are choosing to use the `%` style formatting in this instance?

Comment: @gtlambert no particular reason, `format()` can (and probably should, since it's sort of a "new" non-legacy way) be used though I think I'll just leave the answer as is, the point raised in the answer is still valid regardless of the formatting style. Thanks!

Comment: @alexce of course - I was just interested in case there was a specific reason